# UIViewController within a UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

So I have a viewControllerA, and I want to add another View managed by viewControllerB to it. There is only one UISlider activating a simple action in viewControllerB. It won't crash if I don't touch this UISlider, it will once I use UISlider. I am using ARC. I am using:

```
[self.view addSubView: viewControllerB.view];
```

to add viewControllerB to viewControllerA. Am I missing something? Thanks.

OK. It looks like a really simple situation. I just added one view controller and one action. Here is the demo project code on github: https://github.com/randomor/Demo

The reason why I want this to work is because I have another app that will create a view controller on the spot and add it to anther view. And I don't want to do it modally, because I don't want the new view controller to cover the whole screen. Thanks.

SOLUTION: So I'm now just using the latest ViewController containment API:

```
[self addChildViewController:viewControllerB];
```

It works! as long as I added this line, the event will be passed to its own controller and it stopped crashing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i recommend you, to use the following code

in `ViewControllerA.h`

```
    #import "ViewControllerB.h"
```

in `ViewControllerA.m` (where you want to push the new controller)

```
ViewControllerB *newController = [[ViewControllerB alloc]init];
[self presentModalViewController:newController animated:YES];
```

in `ViewControllerB.m` you will need

```
[self.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

to make it vanish again.

concerning multiple controllers for one open screen (Apple ViewController Programming Guide):

> ```
> Each custom view controller object you create is responsible for managing exactly 
> one screen’s worth of content. The one-to-one correspondence between a view controller 
> and a screen is a very important consideration in the design of your application. 
> You should not use multiple custom view controllers to manage different portions 
> of the same screen. Similarly, you should not use a single custom view controller 
> object to manage multiple screens worth of content.
> ```

Comment: i updated the code - please try it out like that =) it has to work :)

Comment: ok, now I moved the code out from ViewDidLoad to another action triggered by a button, it does work now using the modal method. But what I really want to achieve is not cover the whole screen with it. I want still be able to use the other parts of the parent view.

Comment: then you will have to make the slider a subview of viewcontrollerA, but without having an own controllerB.

Comment: yes, i want to separate it because I don't want to mix the code together. but maybe that's the only way to go? But how are these container viewcontrollers like tabViewcontroller or splitviewcontroller implemented? I found a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046705/display-whole-viewcontroller-within-another-viewcontrollers-view

Comment: yes. this is the way to go. i added a piece of the viewcontroller programming guide from apple to my answer. one controller per screen. 

to your tabbarquestion: the tabbarcontroller 'presents' your actual viewcontroller, it does not handle the interaction from your view.

Comment: +1 for the quote saying not to load multiple view controllers on one screen.  However, in order to get them on the same screen just create a **view** to add to your first view controller.

Comment: thats what i wanted to point out - maybe i didn't state it clear enough. thats what i meant with adding it as subview to 'viewcontrollerA' and handling the interaction there. especially since the only thing he is talking about is to add one simple UISlider =)

Comment: I was just using the slider to demonstrate, but in reality I want other logic that control that area with multiple UI elements, hence a separate controller. :) But @isaac posted an interesting link, hopefully I can find the alternative solution in that link. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: okay :) the link basically repeats that you should not do what you want to do ;) there is really nothing wrong to handle a lot of interaction in the same viewcontroller - use pragma marks and you wont have any problems keeping the overview =)

Answer (score 2):

You should try and avoid the practice of nesting UIViewControllers. While it is technically supported in iOS5, it is ill-advised, for many reasons, including the type of problem that you're having (you have a dangling pointer to a UIViewController, which is why you are crashing).

http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/03/09/abusing-uiviewcontrollers/

Comment: that's a great link. Thanks! i'm also viewing the wwdc11 talk on view controller containment.

Answer (score 1):

Although this question is extremely vague, I imagine that you are not keeping a reference to View Controller B, and so when view B tries to interact with it, it causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Comment: Thanks. How do you keep a reference to viewControllerB? I'm not doing an ivar. I'm just creating it on the spot in ViewDidLoad and add it to the view.

Comment: @randomor The way I've typically seen it done is you create a property on the parent view to hold a reference to the child view.  I don't think this is your problem though because views retain their child views.

Answer (score 0):

What's the object that is set as the target for the slider? If it's a `EXC_BAD_ADDRESS`, then you may not be retaining the target, most probably the view controller for the slider.

Comment: The target for the slider is the viewControllerB cause it owns the slider. I'm basically alloc and init the viewControllerB and add it to the viewControllerA at ViewDidLoad. Yes, it is EXC_BAD_ADDRESS, but I'm using the ARC.